# Previous month Data Against A specific ID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to get previous month's record in a single row against a ID. I am fetching the data from database and i want to add some current value in previous month's value. So i want to fetch previous month's data to add. How is this possible

Comment: Please show us the table(s) schema's and hopefully some sample data.

Comment: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @RahulTripathi sqlexpress 2008

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly:

MYSQL:

```
update old_month u
inner join new_month s on
    u.someid= s.someid
set u.rowtoupdate= s.rowtoupdate
```

Comment: i want to add some value, the value which is saved with month in database i want to fetch and add some value not update it

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:(*Since you have not provided the datecolumn details I am taking one of my own*)

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_name
WHERE DATEPART(m, date_created) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
AND DATEPART(y, date_created) = DATEPART(y, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
AND ID = <YOUR ID>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from YourTable
where Month(YourDateCol)= case when (MONTH(GETDATE())- 1)=0 THEN 12 ELSE MONTH(GETDATE())-1 END
AND YEAR(YourDateCol)= case when (YEAR(GETDATE())- 1)=0 THEN  YEAR(GETDATE())-1 ELSE YEAR(GETDATE()) END 
AND ID = <yourID>
```